# I cannot star a .odg file in a subfolder of Documents

Tags: nautilus

The file is in a subfolder of Documents which is tracked by search. All files in this directory can be starred except for .odg files. I'm trying to figure out why this is.

These files were created by libreoffice Draw in Ubuntu.

Comment: what application was used to create these files and under which OS? please [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: @24601 info added.

Comment: Works fine for me with ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS - a new test.odg file in ~/Documents. Draw v7.2.2.2

Comment: @24601 I am one directory lower ~/Documents/Folder/file.odg. All other files in this folder star, only .odg doesn't. Strange.

Comment: yes, interesting... that seems to be the case with my instance too. One directory lower `~/Documents/Folder/ and the same file does not star although a copy of the same file in the directory above it does. The same issue applies with a different file too from a different application (PDF) so not especially a LO file. Maybe a bug which you should report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect) Can you confirm the file types of others in the lower directory which you say **do star** and add that to your question for clarity.